# AddModelError Not Being Passed Back to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using the asp.net Razor with C#. I am trying to verify that a value entered is a currency but I can't seem to do it correctly.

This is in my PaymentModel:

```
  [Required]
  [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
  [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
  [Display(Name = "Payment Amount:")]
  public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

This is my Prepayment view:

```
@model SuburbanCustPortal.Models.PaymentModel.PrePayment

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Make a payment!";
}

<script>
$(function(){
  $("#AccountId").change(function(){
    var val=$(this).val();
    $("#currentBalance").load("@Url.Action("GetMyValue","Payment")", { custid : val });
    document.forms[0].Amount.focus();
  });
});
</script>

<h2>Make a Payment</h2>

  @using (Html.BeginForm("SendPayment", "Payment", FormMethod.Post))
  {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please correct the errors and try again.")
    <div>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Please enter the amount of the payment below:</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
          Please select an account.
        </div>

        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AccountId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Accounts)

        <div class="editor-label">
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccountBalance)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
          <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel" id="currentBalance">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccountBalance)&nbsp;</label>
        </div>      

        <div class="editor-label">
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Amount)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field focus">
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount, new { @class = "makePaymentText" })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Amount)
        </div>

        <p>
          <input id="btn" class="makePaymentInput" type="submit" value="Pay Now"  onclick="DisableSubmitButton()"/>  
        </p>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  }

This is my Prepayment ActionResult:

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult PrePayment(PaymentModel.PrePayment model)
    {
      var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
      var custs = _client.RequestCustomersForAccount(User.Identity.Name);
      foreach (var customerData in custs)
      {
        var acctno = customerData.Branch + customerData.AccountNumber;
        var acctnoname = string.Format(" {0} - {1} ", acctno, customerData.Name);
        // msg += string.Format("*** {0} - {1} ***{2}", customerData.AccountId, acctnoname, Environment.NewLine);
        list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = acctnoname, Value = customerData.AccountId });
      }

      if (custs.Length > 0)
      {
        model.AccountBalance = String.Format("{0:C}", Decimal.Parse(custs[0].TotalBalance));
      }

      ViewBag.Accounts = list;
      return View(model);
    }
```

The post of the view calls SendPayment and this was my check at the begining of the view:

```
    if (model.Amount == 0)
    {    
      ModelState.AddModelError("Amount", "Invalid amount.");
      return RedirectToAction("PrePayment", model);
    }
```

I can't seem to get the PrePayment to get my error back that I sent from AddModelError. I changed it to:

```
    if (model.Amount == 0)
    {    
      ModelState.AddModelError("Amount", "Invalid amount.");
      return View("PrePayment", model);
    }
```

But it never calls the controller and the screen errors out since it doesn't have the data it is expecting.

How do I redirect back to the calling view with the errors?

**==== ADDITIONAL INFO ====**

Here is my PrePayment View:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult PrePayment(PaymentModel.PrePayment model)
{
    var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var custs = _client.RequestCustomersForAccount(User.Identity.Name);
    foreach (var customerData in custs)
    {
      var acctno = customerData.Branch + customerData.AccountNumber;
      var acctnoname = string.Format(" {0} - {1} ", acctno, customerData.Name);
      // msg += string.Format("*** {0} - {1} ***{2}", customerData.AccountId, acctnoname, Environment.NewLine);
      list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = acctnoname, Value = customerData.AccountId });
    }

    if (custs.Length > 0)
    {
      var amt =String.Format("{0:C}", Decimal.Parse(custs[0].TotalBalance));
      model.AccountBalance = amt;
      decimal namt;
      if (decimal.TryParse(amt.Replace(",",string.Empty).Replace("$", string.Empty), out namt))
      {
        model.Amount = namt;
      }
    }
  ViewBag.Accounts = list;
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: That's because of the redirect.

Comment: what are the errors you get?

Comment: I tried View and it never called the controller. How do I get it to call the controller and pass the erros?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, it's just not passing my ModelState.AddModelError back to the original view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues needs to be addressed.

```
1.  return View("PrePayment", model);  
This will not call the controller, as the function name suggests, it only passing your object to the specified "View"(.cshtml file)

2.     return RedirectToAction("PrePayment", model);  
You will not persist modelstate data, because you are doing a redirect.
```

Suggested workflow which will solve your issue. At least it solved mine.

```
1. Get the form to post to "PrePayment" instead of SendPayment and you will create a new method with the following signature and have all you validation logic in the method
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PrePayment(PaymentModel.PrePayment model)

2. If everything goes well then redirect to the success/send payment page depending on your requirement

3. If somehow you need to pass model object onto the next action. Use TempData like following. This will temporarily persist the data till the next action. Then it get disposed:
TempData["payment"]=model;
```

Comment: that's great... explanation of what I'm doing wrong and a great example of how to correct it!  Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

May be you should add a data annotation to your property and use `ModelState.IsValid` property to validate it

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Display(Name = "Payment Amount:")]
[Range(0.01, Double.MaxValue)]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

In your `POST` method, check whether the validation is passed, if not send the model back to the view.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendPayment(PrePayment model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     //do the fun stuff
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: If I just return view, it tries to send it back to PrePayment which it is where it is now. But yet, I did send the model when I tried to call the view. I have modified my code above to show this.

Comment: Thanks for updating it but displaying a message such as "The field Payment Amount: must be between 0.01 and 9000000." seems kind of sloppy to me. Also, the message is displaying as soon as the form starts.

Comment: You can customize the error message in the data annotation. Are you validating your page on load ?

Comment: I have added my PrePayment controller that loads that view. I am not doing any validation in it.